# Function overload ambiguity when passing function object

Tags: c++, overloading

I've broken a bit of code in a way that has me scratching my head. The following demonstrates the issue (*complete code at http://ideone.com/TsRPcx*):

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<bool()> BoolCallback;
typedef std::function<void()> VoidCallback;

// Support two types of callback
void scan( BoolCallback func ) {}
void scan( VoidCallback func ) {}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    scan( [] {} );                          // Original, unambiguous.
    scan( [] { return true; } );            // New, broken call. Ambiguous.
}
```

With gcc 5.1, the first call compiles fine, but the second complains that the `call of overloaded ‘scan(main(int, char**)::<lambda()>)’ is ambiguous`. So the first question is, how can one of those calls be fine, and the other ambiguous?

Thinking this might have something to do with the lambda expressions I was using, I tried some other approaches (spoiler alert: they all produce the same result):

```
    scan( []() -> void {} );                // Unambiguous
    scan( []() -> bool { return true; } );  // Ambiguous

    auto vcb = []() -> void {};
    auto bcb = []() -> bool { return true; };
    scan( vcb );                            // Unambiguous
    scan( bcb );                            // Ambiguous

    extern void voidCallback();
    extern bool boolCallback();
    scan( voidCallback );                   // Unambiguous
    scan( boolCallback );                   // Ambiguous, so it's not the lambdas

    scan( (VoidCallback)vcb );              // Unambiguous
    scan( (BoolCallback)bcb );              // Eureka!
```

An explicit cast resolves the ambiguity, as does declaring `bcb` above explicitly as `BoolCallback` instead of `auto` (not shown).

Finally, I tried changing the callback types:

```
typedef void (*VoidCallback)();
typedef bool (*BoolCallback)();
```

Hmmm... This works fine for all the cases above. It's not a solution, since this is library code which needs the generality provided by `std::function`, but it is interesting.

Can someone shed some light on why this is unambiguous for `std::function` objects that return no value, or for primitive function pointers in any case, but is ambiguous otherwise?

Comment: The lambda, having a unique class type, has to be converted to a `std::function`. The converting constructor (template) of `std::function<F>` rejects those function object types that are incompatible to its signature `F`. There's a [specific exception in this rule](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420) that allows the function object to have *any* return type if the signature `F` has return type `void`. That's why `[]() -> bool {}` can be converted to a `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: @dyp that comment, and that link with it, are simply stellar. It deserves upticks galore and quite-likely promotion to full-answer, even if this is a duplicate.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, thank you. I'm currently updating my linked answer.